# Dependency distribution using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, maven-shade-plugin, minecraft-forge, gradle-shadow-plugin

I'm writing a Minecraft mod and no, I don't need help with Java.  I've gotten that all working :).  However, I am having some troubles with dependancies.  You see, my mod requires JGit.  I attempted to include JGit using "shade" in the build.gradle, but that only worked in a development environment.  As soon as I tried to distribute the built jar, I found out that it does not work properly.

It was suggested to me that I use the "shadow" plugin -- however, when I attempted to do this, building the mod would not work properly (all imports would fail to find JGit).  I don't know if this is my fault, shadow's fault, or ForgeGradle's fault.  I hope it is my fault, because that's fixable!

[This](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/58663-external-dependency-does-not-work-in-normal-mc/) post contains some of the things I've tried with my build.gradle.  It didn't work.

The last build.gradle I've tried as of writing this post is [here](https://pastebin.com/EZUrCr5e).

```
apparently pastebin can't be linked without me adding code.  The file is too big to look nice in a post so I'm not going to put it here.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with a very similar situation using JGit in a Maven shaded plugin

Comment: I did in fact find a solution -- I would've posted here but I completely forgot about this post!  The build.gradle is here -> https://github.com/KingofGamesYami/CCGit-Rewrite/blob/master/build.gradle

Basically things were failing because certain dependencies were already loaded.  Repackaging them fixed the issue.